# typename, type members and non-type members: is it valid code?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, typename

Consider the following code:

```
struct S {
    struct type {};
    type type;
};

int main() {  
    typename S::type t;
    (void) t;
}
```

Apart for the fact that is far from being a good idea, I was experimenting after having read another question here on SO.
I found that the snippet above is [compiled with no errors by GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/eErtDr) and it is [rejected by clang 3.9](https://godbolt.org/g/Li65kz) with the following error:

> error: typename specifier refers to non-type member 'type' in 'S'

I suspect that clang is right in this case and GCC is wrong (actually, I'm opening an issue to the latter).
Is it the right conclusion or is that a valid use of `typename`?

---

Note: I'm not asking how to solve it, I know how to do that. I'm asking only if this code is valid or not.

Comment: older gcc like 4.4.7 rejects it too : http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Oh2Rp4jWjGPIoIwv

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the standard about the legality of this. Still, `typename` is only mentioned in regards to templates, so maybe it's a violation in spirit? Regardless, the correct and standard way to resolve such a particular ambiguity, seems to be `struct S::type t;`

Comment: @marcinj That seems to be because GCC 4.4.7 does not implement [CWG 382: Allow `typename` outside of templates](http://wg21.link/cwg382).

Comment: cwg 382 working link: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#382

Comment: so its clang wrong - I have found it reports it as fixed : "382 CD1 Allow typename outside of templates Yes (C++11 onwards)" http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html

Comment: update: clang is RIGHT - as cpplearner explained in answer

Comment: @marcinj Actually, also the guys from GCC say they are right: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78286 :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[[temp.res]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#4):

> The usual qualified name lookup is used to find the *qualified-id* even in the presence of `typename`.

That is, unlike the case with *elaborated-type-specifier*s, the name lookup in this case does not ignore non-type names.

[[temp.res]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#3):

> If the *qualified-id* in a *typename-specifier* does not denote a type or a class template, the program is ill-formed.

So the program in question is ill-formed.

[temp.res]/4 also has an example for this:

```
struct A {
  struct X { };
  int X;
};
struct B {
  struct X { };
};
template<class T> void f(T t) {
  typename T::X x;
}
void foo() {
  A a;
  B b;
  f(b);             // OK: T::X refers to B::X
  f(a);             // error: T::X refers to the data member A::X not the struct A::X
}
```

Comment: But `S::type` is a type.

Comment: @GillBates `S::type` is a type name and a non-type name, and the non-type name hides the type name.

Comment: This is template name resolution though, there are none involved in OP's question, I don't think it's safe to say the rules are the same.

Comment: @GillBates All what is involved is the usual qualified name lookup.

Comment: This answer is correct. I got into a discussion about lookup in `typename`-qualified names before; non-type names are not ignored, and so they shadow here. +1

Comment: Is there a simple-language explanation without the need to know the terms from the c++ standard?