# Accessing type members in C++

Tags: c++

Given an container such as a `vector<int>`

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
```

Why does it seem to be quite difficult to access the public type members such as `iterator` and `const_iterator`? As I understand it, these names are part of the class (not the object) and must be accessed via `::` to specify the scope, but is there a reason to forbid `v.const_iterator` when `v` is known?
Example:

```
int f(v.iterator it) {
    return *it;
}
// or
int g(v::iterator it) {
    return *it;
}
```

A workaround would be using `decltype` as in:

```
int h(decltype(v)::iterator it) {
    return *it;
}
```

But this approach does not even work in classes, as the following fails:

```
class A
{
public:
    int h(decltype(x)::iterator it) {
        return *it;
    }
private:
    vector<int> x;
};
```

### Edit

Just a little sidenote.
As pointed out, the meaning of `v.iterator` would depend on the type of `v` at the point of usage (compile time) ignoring runtime polymorphism. But the same is true for static class members.
Example:

```
struct A
{
    static const int x = 1;
};
struct B : public A
{
    static const int x = 2;
};
void eval()
{
    B b;
    A& ar = b;
    b.x; // 2
    ar.x; // 1, even though ar refers to the same underlying object (by the base type)
}
```

Comment: Types and objects exist are parallel universes in C++ (one mostly compile-time, other mostly run-time.) Dot is applied to objects, and thus should work in run-time, and thus is not for types. As a side note, you can use `auto` here to save some typing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux sorry I meant the last example

Comment: How would `auto` in the function parameter of `A::h` work? It does not compile in clang with c++17 for me.

Comment: Your last example would work fine if you moved `x` so it was declared *before* it was used in `decltype(x)`.

Comment: `decltype()` is not a workaround but the way to do it, and it works in classes, you just need to define that variable before you use it.

Comment: `return *it + *(++it);` great example with UB :)

Comment: @Slava I was surprised to not get sequence point warnings with either clang or gcc. Are iterators too complicated for that?

Comment: @Slava thanks for pointing that out, though this might be unspecified, not undefined since c++17 as the order of evaluation for function arguments are unspecified.

Comment: How is that related to order of evaluation of function arguments?

Comment: I retract my statement, this is probably UB. I will remove this from the question :)

Comment: If you just change the order in your class, to `class A
{
private:
    vector<int> x;
public:
    int h(decltype(x)::iterator it) {
        return *it + *(++it);
    }
};` it works just fine. The variable is defined before usage. But, funny things happen, when name clash `class A { class B { }; int B; };`

Comment: `auto iter = v.begin();`

Answer (score 2):

As @Slava pointed out in comments, `decltype(x)` is the way to do it:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
int f(decltype(v)::iterator it) {
    return *it;
}

int g(decltype(v)::iterator it) {
    return *it;
}

class A
{
private:
    vector<int> x;
public:
    int h(decltype(x)::iterator it) {
        return *it;
    }
};
```

The member access `.` operator and scope resolution operator `::` may not be overloaded. And as you might deduce from the names, `.` is used to [access members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access), while `::` is used to access [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {
    class iterator { };

    // no need for typename, compiler knows that we mean typedef B::iterator, as he can only find it
    iterator iterator1;

    // member named the same as class, ops!
    int iterator;

    // we need to use typename here, B::iterator is resolved as member
    // iterator iteartor3;
    typename B::iterator iterator2;
};

int main() {
    B bobj;

    // we access the member iterator inside b
    bobj.iterator = 1;

    // we declare object of B::iterator type
    // we need to tell compiler that we want only types
    typename B::iterator iterator;

    // this will work too
    typename decltype(bobj)::iterator iterator2;

    // we declare a member pointer to the iterator member inside some B class
    // no typename, as I want pointer to member, not pointer to... type
    int B::* pointer = &B::iterator;

    // this is just a pointer to the iterator specifically in bobj class
    int * pointer2 = &bobj.iterator;

    // foo(bar) 
    bobj.*pointer = 1;

    // this will work as expected
    int decltype(bobj)::* pointer3 = &B::iterator;
}
```

Also, there are no "type members" in C++ (at least I couldn't find them in C++ standard). Classes and enumerations and typedefs declarations declared in a class as members are called "nested types" or "nested classes".

Comment: A type member *is* a member.

Comment: Interesting example, but strangely it does not compile in clang: https://godbolt.org/z/HTZ3Bg

Comment: ! And works in gcc. I felt this program was invalid, but couldn't find why. [Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523513/typename-type-members-and-non-type-members-is-it-valid-code).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, C++ lets you get either values or types when you access them through `::`. So `MyType::AnotherType` is fine as well as `MyType::AValue`. When you go through an instance with `.`, it only means it want to resolve a symbol which is a kind of a value (field, func, etc.). Hope that helps.

Comment: The question.is not about *what* C++ is doing but *why*.